# Questions about Quantum theory of light

Tags: photons, photoelectric-effect

I'm an electrical engineer and this my first course about modern physics.

In quantum theory of light, Einstein proposed that the light has a particle property and each photon has an energy equal to

$E=hf$

where $h$ is Planck constant and $f$ is the frequency of the electromagnetic wave.

My question is as follows: Why must the energy of the photon be totally absorbed when it hits an electron?

As an example: if a photon has an energy of $3eV$ and hits an electron, this photon will be totally absorbed. Why does this happen?

Why can't a fragment of this photon energy just absorbed by the electron?

Comment: No, see Compton scattering for example.

Comment: It actually is possible for electron to absorb only part of photon energy, look up Compton scattering

Comment: Photons can be absorbed or can scatter. They don't have to be absorbed. Photons can also inelastically scatter, whereby only a portion of their energy is absorbed. Some other things to google: "Raman scattering" and "Inelastic X-ray scattering"

Comment: Also for googling: "Fermi's Golden Rule." This is a common way to calculate the "cross-section" or "rate" for the various processes mentioned above.

Comment: @hft 

but the equation that explained photoelectric effect was 

$hf=\phi+K.E$ which says that the total energy of photon will be absorbed 

let's suppose that the work function of some material is $2ev$ and suppose that a light of energy $10eV$ in incident on this material why can't an electron absorb  just $5eV$ of this incident photon ?

Comment: @Mans You are presenting but one equation, the one you learned in your introductory course. There are many other equations in the entirety of modern physics. The equation you are using pre-supposes the energy of the photon is absorbed entirely. This is a common tree-level process, with a single vertex, so it is reasonable to consider first. But there are other possibilities.

Comment: @hft

so, you say that there are other possibilities that the photon can't be totally absorbed 
then why in the photoelectric effect supposes that it must be totally absorbed?
and can this example happen '' let's suppose that the work function of some material is $2eV$ and suppose that a light of energy $10eV$ in incident on this material why can't an electron absorb just $5eV$ of this incident photon?''

Comment: Photoelectric effect is about absorption. Suppose a high energy photon is "totally" absorbed by an atom (thereby kicking out a deep "core electron"  to produce a "photoelectron"). That process is described by a single tree level diagram with one vertex. Next the "core hole" can be filled by another electron dropping into the "hole" left behind (another single vertex diagram). That will cause the *emission* of a photon of lower energy. This is what inelastic scattering looks like (similar to Raman at optical energies).

Comment: So, anyways, in a single absorption event (like your book describes for their description of the photoelectric effect), the whole amount of energy has to be absorbed. Here I am talking about the single interaction vertex diagram. There's no way to not absorb the entire photon at tree level with one vertex. But later (e.g., as part of a separate tree-level event) a photon can be emitted.

Comment: @hft 

but why the photoelectric effect suppose that it must be entirely absorbed ?

that what i'm asking about

Comment: In equations, the lowest order interaction looks like: $\vec p \cdot A$. The $A$ term is linear in the photon creation and annihilations operators. It can only either create exactly one or destroy exactly one photon. This is what I mean when I'm talking about "tree-level with one vertex." This is the lowest order (and highest probability in most cases since the interaction is weak) interaction. This is what causes absorption (and the photoelectric effect at lowest order). Sorry I do not have time to write at this time.

Comment: When we do Quantum Mechanics we calculate transition rates and cross sections using pertubation theory. This mean we look at matrix elements of the interaction. The interactions look like $H_{int}\sim e\vec p \cdot \vec A$ and $e^2\vec A\cdot \vec A$. The former is what causes absorption (at lowest order).

Comment: @hft 

well I don't know about most of what you've written as I said it's the first time I take an modern physics course what I'm asking an answer that fit likely with the scope of the course 
because in the lecture of the photoelectric effect my professor have shown us the proposal of Einstein and said that a photon must be absorbed entirely my question why Einstein proposed this and what is the proof of his proposal ?

Comment: @Mans It's not clear how you would like this explained or proven to you. Are you asking about experimental proof of the photoelectric effect? Are you asking for a theoretical derivation? If the latter, then what do you propose as the starting point? The QED hamiltonian? Does your textbook offer some further explanation?

Comment: Oscillation and frequency .... see my answer below.

Comment: @Mans A photon is simply the amount of energy, momentum and angular momentum that is being transferred between the electromagnetic field and an external system. I don't know what it would even mean to absorbs "half a photon". That would simply be a different photon, but it would still be the entire photon.

Answer (score 1):

"why Einstein proposed this and what is the proof of his proposal?" He had an experimentally observed phenomenon. He proposed a model for it. The model made additional predictions. Most importantly, it predicted the maximum energy of the photoelectron. Experiments confirmed it. That's the proof.

Note that Einstein's model doesn't require that all of the photon's energy is always transferred to the electron, but it's an easy starting assumption.

Comment: "According to the assumption to be contemplated here, when a light ray is spreading from a point, the energy is not distributed continuously over ever-increasing spaces, but consists of a finite number of energy quanta that are localized in points in space, move without dividing, and can be absorbed or generated only as a whole." A. Einstein in " On a Heuristic Point of View about the Creation and Conversion of Light". A remarkable sentence, especially since it is Einstein's greatest mistake in addition to being one of his greatest insights.

Comment: @John Doty 
then if Einstein's model doesn't require that all of the photon's energy is always transferred to the electron why we write this equation $hf=\phi+K.E$ that describe photoelectric effect ?

Comment: @Mans Essentially, we call it the photoelectric effect when the photon is absorbed. We call it inelastic scattering when it isn't. These are man-made distinctions. For visible light, inelastic scattering is rare in the sort of target that demonstrates the photoelectric effect. Not so for gamma rays. In experiments, the photoelectrons usually have less energy than your $K$, although we attribute this to other energy loss mechanisms. The important features of the model are delivery of the energy in quanta $hf$ and threshold $\phi$ for photoelectron ejection.

Comment: The energy and frequency are key for energy transfer of oscillators.

Answer (score 0):

Once the electron absorbs the photon and has left the solid state, it becomes a a so called *free electron*, which means an electron which is not interacting with something else. However, for a free electron it is impossible to emits a photon. The reason behind this is that it is impossible to satisfy both, the energy conservation and the momentum conservation law. Therefore, while we usually omit the solid in the description of the photoelectric effect, it is in fact necessary to satisfy the momentum conservation.

However, if you are interested in the **inelastic scattering of a photon on a solid state**, there is nothing wrong with that in principle. However, we do not call this photoelectric effect, but use different names, like *Brillouin scattering*, *Raman scattering*, or many else.

Comment: Or "bound electron Compton scattering".

Comment: I'm sure there are many names used for this process. I'm not an expert in solid state physics. Therefore, I changed the last sentence to make it more general. Hope this helps and does not makes it more confusing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Every photon is created by an atom/electron and ends at an atom/electron.  In addition to energy each photon has frequency and it is this frequency the resonants with the electron upon absorption.

The Compton/Gamma ray examples are extremes .... one can say still say the the single photon interacted with a single electron whose energy becomes extremely high to unpredictable levels.... it can relax to other levels releasing other lower (but high) energy photons .... and so on and so on.

The fundemental  concept of QM is based on oscillator theory .... and oscillation is key when energy transfer is selective.

Comment: Absorption and scattering processes are not necessarily resonant.

Answer (score -3):

The "particle" nomenclature is a very unfortunate choice. It suggests that light can be understood as being made of atomistic constituents. That is not so. "A photon" is merely the energy, momentum and angular momentum that is being exchanged between an electromagnetic field and an external system during an irreversible microscopic energy transfer. Energy, momentum and angular momentum are properties of the physical field but they do not have object character like the prevailing language suggests.

Energy and momentum are not quantized, they can take arbitrary values. Angular momentum (spin), however is. It can only change in multiples of a Planck unit. That is the difference between such energy transfers in classical mechanics and in quantum mechanics.

That "energy must be totally absorbed" is simply a consequence of the irreversible nature of a measurement process. If we want to "measure" how much work the electromagnetic field has done on our measurement system, then we have to actually let it perform that much work.

Having said that, it's a little more complicated than that, still. There are "weak" measurement processes in quantum mechanics where not all of the energy or momentum of the primary quantum are being absorbed by the measurement system. In quantum field theory these processes are often called "weak scattering" and they lead to the formation of "particle tracks", in non-relativistic theory we speak about "entanglement".

Comment: See my answer on oscillation.

Comment: @PhysicsDave You are welcome to find "oscillation" in nuclear decay.